# can't read one array csv file corrently with tf.decode_csv()

Tags: tensorflow

I have hundreds of csv files, each of them contains one array, which is the input array of my network.
I tried to use `tf.data.TextLineDataset` to generate a dataset of csv file names and use `dataset.map()` to read them.  However, I get very confused with how to use `tf.decode_csv()`

Say the csv content is

```
1 2 3 4 5 ... 100
```

Then using:

```
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(['a.csv','b.csv', ...])
dataset.map(proc)
```

Where:

```
def proc(csv):
    array = tf.decode_csv(csv,[0.0 for i in range(1000)])
    return array
```

I get:

```
# array = (tensor, shape=1) * 100
```

If use:

```
def proc(csv):
    array = tf.decode_csv(csv,[[0.0]])
    return array
```

I get:

```
# array = (tensor, shape=1)
```

This means only one value of the array is read.

How should the array be read into `(tensor, shape=100)`?

Answer (score 0):

### a.csv

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

### b.csv

```
6 7 8 9 10
```

### main.py

```
import tensorflow as tf

def _parse_csv(input_vec):
    return tf.io.decode_csv(input, [0.0] * 5, field_dim=" ")

dataset = tf.data.TextLineData(["a.csv", "b.csv"])
dataset = dataset.map(_parse_csv)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
file_op = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(file_op))
    # (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0)

    print(sess.run(file_op))
    # (6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0)
```

You'll have a `100` on line 4 instead of `5`